# Check if not url in validator laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 inputs with social accounts, I need get login this social accounts. I need deny write links in this inputs. How I can do it?

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'google_plus' => 'required|not:url',
        'twitter' => 'required|not:url',
    ]);
```

`not:url` not working..

Comment: Question was not clear

Comment: You could use your own validation rule to accomplish that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules. But I don't think it's a problem if an url is inserted. By using blade you most likely escape all HTML characters by default. So I think you only have to make clear that the user should not insert an url in the input fields but something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
'url'   => ['regex' => '/^((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)$/'],
```